# Creating 3D surface / terrain in ArcGIS Pro WITHOUT 3D extensions?

Tags: arcgis-pro, 3d, terrain

I understand GIS principles, but I am a new user to ArcGIS Pro.

I am currently looking to create a terrain type model / surface in 3D, using a georeferenced .ASC file containing ground heights.

Is this possible using ArcGIS Pro, **without** the 3D extensions?

I spoke to ArcGIS sales and they seemed to suggest it was, but everything I can find online relates to 3D Analyst or Spatial Analyst tools.

Comment: Do you have access to other geospatial packages (QGIS for instance) or are you comfortable with python script?

Comment: This is probably the easiest way to convert .asc to raster using base ArcGIS Pro. However, if you need a .tin or some specific format, let me know. This will certainly be viewable as a 3d model in an ArcPro Scene. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.0/tool-reference/data-management/copy-raster.htm

Comment: Many raster processing tools can be used in ArcPro for free through [whitebox](https://github.com/opengeos/WhiteboxTools-ArcGIS) but it does have limitations on its inputs.